# How to Randomly Shuffle a Linked List in C

Tags: c, algorithm, list, data-structures

I have a Linked List and I want to implement a function:

`Random_Shuffle_List (struct node **Headptr)` - which outputs a list such that every single node is randomly moved from its original position.

Please help me with an efficient algorithm to achieve this.

Comment: Try programmers.stackexchange.com unless you have a real doubt about an implementation you have tried.

Comment: I see several ways to solve the problem, however I wonder if its necessary to use a standard linked list? What you don't want is to move the data but only change the reference pointers/index eitherhow. Next question that comes to mind is: is it necessary to do the change on the list or can't you randomize access when you need to access the list? (It's perhaps not the prefered option if you want to access it more than once)

Comment: Try mergesort; using a random function for the comparison. Make sure that all the nodes have the same chance of beeing first. (or second, ...)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would recommend the naïve approach:

1. Build a pointer array pointing at each node.
2. Shuffle the array. This is way, way easier than randomizing a linked structure.
3. "Re-thread" the list by stepping through the nodes in the array's order.

This uses a relatively tiny bit of extra memory, of course, but I think it's more "efficient" in terms of time to implement (and understand) and probably also run-time, than approaches working directly on the linked list.

Comment: +1. For short lists, the memory overhead will be negligible. Any attempt to work on the list directly will be O(n^2) so it'll be horribly slow for long lists (say >1000 items) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

simply reverse the linked list and and swap the middle node and the end node.I think this will work.complexity would be O(n).

Comment: i am not sure of this answer.please tell me if u feel it is wrong

Answer (score -1):

1. Count the number of nodes in the linked list, say `n`
2. Generate two random integers (`a`, `b`) between `0` and `n`
3. Swap the two nodes `a` and `b`.
4. Repeat the above some `m` times.

This is not a good way, but does not require extra memory as @unwind's suggestion.

One thing could be done with @unwind's solution is by using a window.

1. Fix a window length of say `w`
2. Select a two random nodes in the linked list such that two non-overlapping sublists of 3. length `w` (window) can be formed
3. Build two arrays, each for one window pointing to each note in the list
4. Shuffle each window
5. Shuffle pointers between the two windows
6. Re link the nodes
7. Do the above window selection, shuffling and relinking `m` times.

Comment: a) those methods above don't generate random_shuffle where every permutation has equal probability. 
b) first method is slow as hell (you have to traverse list every time you select two nodes).

Answer (score -1):

one way of doing this is initializing an extra field, that will contain a random number generated by a random function.

```
typedef struct node
{
int data;
int random;
struct node *next;
} card;

for eg, we can give
newnode->random = rand() % (100)  
,which will give random numbers up to 100 to the field.Now Ordering the 
 linked list to ascending or descending according to the random number ,will 
help us to shuffle the nodes .

for (tempnode = start; tempnode->next != NULL; tempnode = tempnode->next)
    for (nextnode = tempnode->next; nextnode->next != NULL; nextnode = 
    nextnode->next)
    {
        if (tempnode->random > nextnode->random)
        {
            swap(tempnode, nextnode);
        }
    }
```