# Shuffling a singly linked list using up to log N extra memory and N log N time

Tags: java, linked-list, shuffle

I am trying to shuffle a linked list by recursively, breaking it into two lists and then merging them to ensure a random shuffle.

The two problems I face are:

1. While I run the program, there is an infinite loop at line 56 where I tell the program to shuffle the first list.
2. I am unable to figure out how to add a dummy variable in case the lengths of list 1 and list 2 vary to ensure randomness in shuffling.

PS - I found it through internet search that the length of 2 lists should be same to ensure randomness but I do not know the logic behind it. Also, please let me know if there is a better way of doing it than I am trying.

Thanks in advance!

```
public class LinkedListShuffle
{
    static public class LinkedList<E>       // static nested class
    {
        private int N = 0;
        private Node first = null;

        public class Node
        {
            E elem;
            Node next;
        }

        public boolean isEmpty()
        {    return N == 0;    }

        public void push (E elem)
        {
            Node oldfirst = first;
            first = new Node(); 
            first.elem = elem;
            first.next = oldfirst;
            N++; 
        }

        public E pop()
        {
            E elem = first.elem;
            first = first.next;
            N--;
            return elem;
        }

        public int size ()
        {    return N;    }

    }

    public static void shuffle(LinkedList l)
    {
        if (l.size() == 1) return;

        LinkedList.Node current = l.first;


        LinkedList l1 = new LinkedList();
        LinkedList l2 = new LinkedList();

        while (! l.isEmpty())
        {
            l1.push(l.pop());
            if (! l.isEmpty()) l2.push(l.pop());
        }
        shuffle(l1);
        shuffle(l2);

        /*------------------------------------------    
        * if (l2.size() < l1.size())
        * introduce a dummy node to ensure the
        * randomness in the process of shuffling
        -----------------------------------------*/

        merge(l, l1, l2);

        /*-----------------------------------------------
        * remove the dummy variable
        * ----------------------------------------------*/       
    }

    public static void merge (LinkedList l, LinkedList l1, LinkedList l2)
    {
        while (l1.size() != 0 && l2.size() != 0)
        {
            double chance = StdRandom.uniform(1);
            if (chance < 0.5) l.push(l1.pop());
            else              l.push(l2.pop());
        }

        if (! l1.isEmpty())
            while (! l1.isEmpty()) l.push(l1.pop());
        if (! l2.isEmpty())
            while (! l2.isEmpty()) l.push(l2.pop());
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        LinkedList<String> l = new LinkedList<String>();
        LinkedList<String> copy = new LinkedList<String>();
        l.push("A"); l.push("B"); l.push("C"); l.push("D");
        l.push("E"); l.push("F"); l.push("G"); l.push("H");
        copy = l;

        while (copy.size() != 0) StdOut.println(copy.pop()+"  ");
        shuffle(l);
        while (l.size() != 0) StdOut.println(l.pop()+"  ");
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your implementation use log n space? Each invocation of split creates 2 new lists that hold references to the objects on the heap (created by client). All the lists should consume (n * 8 + overhead) bytes in total, where 8 bytes is the size of a reference in the HotSpot JVM. Clearly, that's linear space and more than log n. My answer uses the same amount of space but without needing the dummy node that you apparently lifted without understanding.

Comment: Not log n space, but extra log n space!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are emptying the list when you print it in your main method, prior to calling `shuffle(l)`.

You are assigning the list `l` to a variable called `copy`, but this variable doesn't contain a copy of the list. It refers to the same list. When you call `copy.pop()`, you remove an element from the original list. Therefore you call `shuffle` on an empty list.

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    LinkedList<String> l = new LinkedList<String>();
    LinkedList<String> copy = new LinkedList<String>();
    l.push("A"); l.push("B"); l.push("C"); l.push("D");
    l.push("E"); l.push("F"); l.push("G"); l.push("H");
    copy = l;

    while (copy.size() != 0) StdOut.println(copy.pop()+"  "); // remove this line
                                                              // and your method will
                                                              // work
    shuffle(l);
    while (l.size() != 0) StdOut.println(l.pop()+"  ");
}
```

Of course, this means your `shuffle` method can't handle an empty list as input.

This can be solved with a tiny fix :

```
public static void shuffle(LinkedList l)
{
    if (l.size() <= 1) return; // instead of == 1
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But it further leads me to the doubt that to have a copy of the linked list, do I need to separately instantiate it? When using in-built linked list, there is a method to in Java to clone the list. So, how can that be executed.

Comment: Moreover, I am still looking forward to an explanation for the need of dummy variable for randomness. I would appreciate it a lot even if someone could direct me to some other relevant link explaining it. Also, if I am using generics, how do I add and finally remove the dummy variable?

Comment: @Neha regarding the creation of a copy of the list, you can implement a clone() method in your LinkedList class, which would create a new instance and copy to it all the elements of the original list. That's what clone() of the built in LinkedList does.

Comment: @Neha As for the dummy variable, I find it hard to believe that a difference of one between the sizes of the two lists would make much of a difference in the randomness of the shuffle. Perhaps the source where you found that meant that the two lists should be similar in size. Adding a dummy element to the list only to remove it later seems meaningless to me.

Comment: Here is the source where I read about dummy variable - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167630/algorithm-for-shuffling-a-linked-list-in-n-log-n-time/12168162#12168162

Answer (score 0):

I think the randomness can be introduced in the splitting stage, in which case the merge simply needs to concatenate 2 randomly shuffled lists. Following is an implementation using a `LinkedBag` Linked List implementation from Robert Sedgewick's algo course, which is clearly where you got your homework from.

```
public static <T> LinkedBag<T> shuffle(LinkedBag<T> ll) {
    if (ll.size() <= 1) return ll;

    LinkedBag<T>[] sublists = split(ll);

    LinkedBag<T> l1 = shuffle(sublists[0]);
    LinkedBag<T> l2 = shuffle(sublists[1]);

    return merge(l1, l2);
}

private static <T> LinkedBag<T>[] split(LinkedBag<T> ll) {
    LinkedBag<T> l1 = new LinkedBag<>();
    LinkedBag<T> l2 = new LinkedBag<>();

    Iterator<T> it = ll.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        if (StdRandom.bernoulli())
            l1.add(it.next());
        else
            l2.add(it.next());
    }

    return (LinkedBag<T>[]) new LinkedBag<?>[]{l1, l2};
}

private static <T> LinkedBag<T> merge(LinkedBag<T> l1, LinkedBag<T> l2) {
    Iterator<T> it = l2.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        l1.add(it.next());
    }
    return l1;
}
```