# std::shuffle doesn't compile with std::list

Tags: c++, list, std, shuffle

I'm trying to shuffle some list of generated elements. Here is the code:

```
std::default_random_engine generator (10);
std::list<int> list(10);

int n = 0;
std::generate(list.begin(), list.end(), [&]{ return n++; });
std::shuffle(list.begin(), list.end(), generator);
```

It doens't compile. Here are the errors:

```
/include/c++/v1/algorithm:3059:34: Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::__list_iterator<int, void *>' and 'std::__1::__list_iterator<int, void *>')
main.cpp:1:10: In file included from main.cpp:1:

/include/c++/v1/random:1641:10: In file included from /bin/../include/c++/v1/random:1641:

main.cpp:37:10: In instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::shuffle<std::__1::__list_iterator<int, void *>, std::__1::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned int, 48271, 0, 2147483647> &>' requested here
/include/c++/v1/iterator:622:1: Candidate template ignored: could not match 'reverse_iterator' against '__list_iterator'
/include/c++/v1/iterator:1017:1: Candidate template ignored: could not match 'move_iterator' against '__list_iterator'
/include/c++/v1/iterator:1369:1: Candidate template ignored: could not match '__wrap_iter' against '__list_iterator'
/include/c++/v1/string:486:11: Candidate template ignored: could not match 'fpos' against '__list_iterator'
```

Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 14):

`std::list` does not provide random access to its elements, which `std::shuffle()` requires. This is how the signature of `std::shuffle()` looks like in its specification (paragraph 25.3.12 of the C++ Standard):

```
template<class RandomAccessIterator, class UniformRandomNumberGenerator>
void shuffle(RandomAccessIterator first,
             RandomAccessIterator last,
             UniformRandomNumberGenerator&& g);
```

If you can, consider using an `std::vector` instead - which, by the way, you are encouraged to use as the default sequential container by the C++ Standard itself.

As an example ([live demo on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf28112e2c06b6b2)):

```
int main()
{
    std::default_random_engine generator(10);
    std::vector<int> v(10);

    std::iota(begin(v), end(v), 0);
    std::shuffle(begin(v), end(v), generator);

    for (auto x : v) { std::cout << x; }
}
```

The `std::iota()` algorithm is just a simpler alternative to your particular usage of `std::generate`.

Comment: The `iota` call isn't guaranteed to pickup `std::iota` via ADL.

Comment: @T.C.: Right, vector iterators could be pointers. I'd better qualify that call - and the one below, just for consistency.

Answer (score 9):

[`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) requires random access iterators. `std::list` doesn't provide those. You need a different container, such as `std::vector`.

If you really need `std::list`, you may need to implement the shuffling in a dedicated algorithm. But first make sure you really need it. Often times people think they need `std::list` when they really need `std::vector`.

Comment: Using std::shuffle on a std::list via an intermediate vector is fairly simple though and can have the advantage of preserving references to the list elements (see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

[algorithms.general]/2, declaration of `shuffle`:

> ```
> template<class RandomAccessIterator, class UniformRandomNumberGenerator>
> void shuffle(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last,
>               UniformRandomNumberGenerator&& rand);
> ```
>
> [..]
>
> If an algorithm’s template parameter is `RandomAccessIterator` [..]
>   **the actual template argument shall satisfy the requirements of a random-access iterator (24.2.7).**

Clearly `std::list` only provides bidirectional iterators. Try to use a container that does provide random-access iterators instead.

Answer (score 1):

[AndyProwl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1932150/andy-prowl) correctly explains why the code doesn't compile, and notes that it's often more appropriate to use a std::vector than a std::list. However, [juanchopanza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661519/juanchopanza) scaremongers slightly in his claim that shuffling a std::list requires a dedicated algorithm. In fact, it is easy to shuffle a std::list using std::shuffle, by way of an intermediate vector of references (and using the move constructor, if appropriate):

```
#include <numeric>
#include <random>

template <typename T, typename URBG>
void shuffle(std::list<T>& l, URBG&& urbg)
{
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const T>> v(l.begin(), l.end());
    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), urbg);
    std::list<T> shuffled;
    for (auto &ref : v) shuffled.push_back(std::move(ref.get()));
    l.swap(shuffled);
}

int main()
{
    std::list<int> l(10);
    std::iota(l.begin(), l.end(), 0);
    shuffle(l, std::mt19937{ std::random_device{}() });
    for (auto x : l) std::cout << x << " ";
}
```

In fact, we can do even better: since it is possible to move elements between lists without invalidating iterators or references, we can even shuffle lists of objects that are neither copyable nor movable, and (more significantly perhaps) also ensure that shuffling preserves references to list elements.

```
template <typename T, typename URBG>
void shuffle(std::list<T>& l, URBG&& urbg)
{
    std::vector<std::list<T>::const_iterator> v;
    for (auto it = l.cbegin(); it != l.cend(); ++it) v.push_back(it);
    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), urbg);
    std::list<T> shuffled;
    for (auto &it : v) shuffled.splice(shuffled.end(), l, it);
    l.swap(shuffled);
}
```

Of course both these solutions have an O(n) space overhead for the vector of references (or iterators). If that's a problem then you can implement a slower O(n log n) time algorithm that uses just O(1) space, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167630/algorithm-for-shuffling-a-linked-list-in-n-log-n-time/27624106#27624106). Though you'd probably save more space by switching to std::forward_list anyway.